# regex to capture group if group is before or after a specific string

Tags: python, regex

i want to grab a number if the number is before or after a certain text ("b"), using python and a single regex. The "single" here is important....

so the following case should match (even if the first is optional as will never happen...)

- b 1 b
- b 2 c
- c 3 b

this should not:

- c 4 d

i toyed around (lookahead and back) but nothing really worked.
i belive this should be possible using some look around stuff and ... magic? But i can't figure out how...

see this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4mv6Wa/1) for a starting point...

if this is not possible, why?
if this is possible, how?

Comment: You may use this regex `r'(?<=\bb )\d+|\d+(?= b\b)'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the example you have given, the following pattern will match any number (group of one or more consecutive numerical digits) preceded by `b`  **or** followed by  `b`.

```
(?<=b\s)\d+|\d+(?=\sb)
```

#### First clause `(?<=b\s)\d+`

Look-back to check for `b`  and match one or more following numerical digits

#### or `|`

Conditional telling engine to check second clause if first does not produce match.

#### Second clause `\d+(?=\sb)`

Match one or more numerical digits only if followed by  `b` as defined by look-ahead.

Comment: because the link to the regex101 was wrong. Sorry....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tested in Python (as question tagged Python) using bultin `re` module as follows.

```python
>>> text = '''
... b 1 b
... b 2 c
... c 3 b
... c 4 d
... '''
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=b\s)\d+|\d+(?=\sb)')
>>> for m in re.findall(pattern, text):
...    print(m)
...
1
2
3
```

Am I missing something here? Thought this was what OP was after - matches number only when preceded by `b ` **or** followed by ` b` .

Comment: one additional problem: In python the result of the match is a tupel of the first and second match. Would be nice to have a regex where only one match (of the \d+) comes back...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using two regex matchers, one to capture the number if it before the text ("b"), and one to do so if it is after the text.

**To match numbers before text 'b'**

```
/([0-9]+)b/g
```

**To match numbers after text 'b'**

```
/b([0-9]+)/g
```

Comment: That's my actual solution, but i want a solution with a single regex... The context is that  If i use wto regexes one will fail and trigger an  error, and if i can avoid dealing with this in the error handler i'll be glad.

Comment: You can use the 'or' quantifier in regex to join both. This works for javascript, you can try it out on python.
/b([0-9]+)|([0-9]+)b/g